# Google ReCAPTCHA callback function not working

Tags: javascript, html, recaptcha

I use Google's reCAPTCHA on my website and I'm having problems getting it to call a callback function. After a user has successfully passed the captcha I want to call a function. I use a div with these attributes to render the captcha:

```
class='g-recaptcha' data-sitekey='keyhere' data-callback='alert(1);'
```

However, I can't get the `alert(1);` to trigger, nothing happens when I fill out the captcha. Everything else about the captcha works fine, I just can't get it to call the function. What could I be doing wrong?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I haven't used it, so I don't know if this will help, but looking at the few examples online that I can find, it looks like `data-callback` should be a function name, not the script body:

```
class='g-recaptcha' data-callback='doSomething'

function doSomething() { alert(1); }
```

Comment: You are right, thanks. I did try writing the function name before, but I put a semicolon after the name which caused it to not work.